# How to get all google play purchases across multiple google accounts with billingClient

Tags: android, billingclient

I'm using [queryPurchasesAsync](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#queryPurchasesAsync(java.lang.String,%20com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesResponseListener)) to query the purchases of the user. Now if there are multiple accounts, I would expect that any purchase across these accounts would show up. But thats not the case. Is there a way to get all purchases across the accounts?

Answer (score 0):

No, the billing client can only handle one account at a time.

Its based on the email the user is signed in in the Google Play Console.

Maybe https://developers.google.com/android-publisher can help in providing more information

Comment: So you suggest that in the app I show the currently used account. And the user should be able to change that account.

I'm wondering how Android decides which account is used? Which SDK could be used for this approach?

Comment: Android usually handles which account to use based on which account is currently logged in on the Google Play store. I did some research and I don't think Google SignIn is the right way to go. If users go to your app and they are not signed in as the user who subscribed to your in-app item, you can have message stating: "You don't have this item, if you do, try signing in in your Google Play console" or something to that degree.

Comment: I know that you can switch accounts in Google Play Store. But when I switched between my accounts and checked the payment status in my app, it was not properly reflected. So I think it had no effect to change the account in Google Play Store App. Unforutunately I also don't know what is happening in the billing library: I do not provide a account explicitly. Maybe increasing some log level would printout the accounts for which the purchases are checked?